# Find the vertices and foci of the equation $x^2=4y-2y^2$

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

> $$x^2=4y-2y^2$$

I figured out it was an ellipse but I don't know where to go next. I don't know how to modify it to where it fulfills the form of an ellipse. Please help.

Comment: Hint: complete the square $\;x^2+2(y^2-2y+1)=2\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
x^2=4y-2y^2&\iff x^2+2y^2-4y=0\\
&\iff x^2+ 2(y^2-2y)=0\\
&\iff x^2+2(y^2-2y+1)=2\\
&\iff x^2+2(y-1)^2=2\\
&\iff \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{(y-1)^2}{1}=1. 
\end{align}$$
Can you now find the vertices, and foci?

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even think of completing the square inside there, thank you!